# How to change the endpoint url using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have used the below at the test suite level

```
result = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport.prompt("Please select the enviornment", "Environment", ['SIT', 'UAT']);
```

on running the test suite, i get the drop down to select a property. Now after selecting the property, it has to set the end point URL for the all the test cases and do the run.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear - what are you asking?

Comment: What i am trying to do is to change the endpoint URL in SOAP UI using groovy. I want to change using the prompt dialog box and select the property value. On selection of that property the test suite should run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `testStep` has a `endpoint` property which is the endpoint url to invoke for this `testStep`. If you want to change all endpoint for each `testStep` inside each `testCase` in your `testSuite` you can loop it through each one changing this property. To do this you can use for example a groovy `testStep`with the follow code:

```
def result = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport.prompt("Please select the enviornment", "Environment", ['SIT', 'UAT'])
def testcases = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseList()
// for all testCases in your test suite...
testcases.each { testcase ->
    // for all testStep inside testCase...
    def teststeps = testcase.getTestStepList() 
    teststeps.each { teststep ->
        teststep.setPropertyValue('endpoint','http://yourUrl')
    }
}
```

If you prefer to do the same inside `Setup script` on your `testSuite` you've to change the code above a bit since there is no `testrunner` in the context (instead you can use directly `testSuite` var).So if you want to put the code inside `Setup script` instead of inside in groovy `testStep` you can use the follow code:

```
def result = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport.prompt("Please select the enviornment", "Environment", ['SIT', 'UAT'])
def testcases = testSuite.getTestCaseList()
testcases.each { testcase ->
    def teststeps = testcase.getTestStepList() 
    teststeps.each { teststep ->
        teststep.setPropertyValue('endpoint','http://yourUrl')
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

You can also set all the `endpoint` properties, plus `username` and `password` like this:

- open the interface viewer (right click on the interface)
- go to the 'Service Endpoints' tab
- Select the endpoint you want to use for your testing session
- click assign, and select where to you want to assign this endpoint.

Happy testing!